# How to pass multiple id's/values in the gremlin query?

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, gremlinpython, tinkerpop

How to pass multiple id's/values in the gremlin query?

```
g.V().hasNot(T.id, [need_to_pass_multiple_id's]).....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found `without()`. This traversal helps to remove the given id's

```
g.V().has(T.id, without('id1', 'id2'))
```

Comment: The Gremlin in your answer is not valid. The correct form is `g.V().hasId(without('id1','id2'))` or `g.V().has(id,without('id1','id2'))`. If you really want the double negative form then you would just use `within`. `hasNot` works on property keys.